# Windows 2003 hidden anonymous shares with IP restriction

Tags: network-share

I have created anonymous(everyone account) "hidden" shares on Windows 2003 to let our ASP.NET application access it from another server without credentials. I have added $ to share name to hide it from other users, but actually this is not solution because such shares can be easily discovered by other OS or some tools on Win.
Can I restrict shared folder access by IP?

Regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do that short of playing with a specialized set of firewall rules; have you considered instead having the application run with particular privileges and giving that application access to the share via that privilege account? I.e., application runs as user foo, and you give foo specific access to the share or folder at the NTFS level (or share level, if you have it set so that would work; I often give shares full access to anyone but restrict everything at the filesystem level for fine-grained access control without troubleshooting interaction between shares and filesystem permissions...)